# how to do mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, search, replace

Not to a specific query but all of software queries to be converted from mysql to mysqli due to the advent of PHP 7. It is a very old coding and so there are many occurrences as such. Piece of string or syntax is    mysql_query($query, $link);to be converted to mysqli_query($link, $query); $link1, $link2 can be for different database connections.

Comment: Where have you declared `$link1` and `$link2`? It's the best if you specify `$link` in some config file and include it on every page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). I have not checked that my expression works as advertised, and regular expression syntax varies depending on the tool you use. But in general it should work this way:

- Search for `mysql_query\(("[^"]*"), *(\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)`
- Replace with `mysqli_query($2, $1)`

As an example, in Eclipse IDE, use "Search/File...", tick the checkbox "Regular expression", specify "*.php" as file name pattern and enter this as under "Containing text":

```
mysql_query\(("[^"]*"), *(\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
```

Then hit the "Replace..." button and enter this under "With":

```
mysqli_query($1, $2)
```

Click Preview to check the results. If done correctly, this can update hundreds of files within seconds. Remember to test your code afterwards.

Comment: I have tested it and it is working. This is going to save my precious time, Axel! Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Axel, what if the query is like `mysqli_query("select field1, field2 from table where row1 = '".$var1."' and row2 = '".$var2."' limit 1", $linkx)`. How to pick and interchange them?

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution:

Firstly, remove your `mysql` extension so the functions like `mysql_query` will not be defined.

Secondly, write functions like this:

```
function mysql_query($q, $l){
    mysqli_query($l, $q);
}
```

I mean, rewrite all mysql functions to call mysqli.

Then it may work well.

Of course, if your code have used so many `mysql` features, then this may not work well. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, damn, I like you.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Thank you. If you like it, then you can give me a upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Thanks for your appreciation :)

Comment: It is good, but I need to replace code to save time. In your solution I would have to write the function and after that will have to write a code for each query to call that function individually.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, solution from @Axel is not working on my version of the Eclipse.

To replace the code:

```
mysql_query($1, $2)
```

I have used this regex search and it worked:

```
mysql_query\((\$.*), (\$.*)\)
```

To replace it with:

```
mysqli_query($2, $1)
```